# Idea for timer work to slow (Work with another form) Window form c#

Tags: c#, timer

My project have a MainForm, i show F_Insert and set MdiParent for MainForm

```
F_Insert f = new F_Insert();
f.MdiParent = this;  
f.Show()
```

And my Upload method, this method in MainForm.

```
private void upload ()
{
  //Do something to upload, it give 3s to upload complete
}
```

And i want to upload data to Netwrok server every 10s. But the upload processing give 3s to upload data completely.

I use WindowForm.Timer and set tick every 10s to Method Upload. The problem is when Timer tick. I can't do anything, i can't insert new data. After 3s, i can do it normaly. It's so bad if i am a customer.

Please give me some idea to improve it.

Thank my friend !!!!

Comment: Surely you could program a way for the new data to be selected with each tick. For instance, you could have an integer that increments with each upload, and the integer could lead to the location of the appropriate data (e.g. in a Dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

You could use some async programming pattern.
You can use e.g. Backgroundworker for wrapping the upload process and start it async. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

You can also use Task framework (or await / async from .NET 4.5) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)